# CallBack с фрейма в родитель

Tags: javascript

Заранее прошу прощения за странный вопрос

Есть сайт, который во фрейме отрывает другие (специфические) сайты.
Сайт, открывающийся во фрейме подлючает библиотеку `api`, который предстовляет собой оболочку для `parent.postMessage()`.

И вот проблема. Как реализовать callback через `postMessage()`
Смысл в том, чтобы, через `api` можно было отправить назад во фрейм результат запроса, Сейчас реализовано так:

```
eos.api.set_data('data', (result)=>{
});
```

Сейчас `api` реализова так

```
let eos = {
   api: {
        set_data : (res, fun) => {
           //Что делать с fun(), что бы его можно было визвать из `patern`
           parent.postMessage(res,'***')
        }
    }
}
```

Т.е в родителе выполнятся фукция из `api (set_data)` и ее результат нужно обратно отправить в фрейм, и  именно в callback функцию, переданою вторим парамертом api.

Еще раз прошу прощение за, возможно непонятный вопрос.

Все в коменрарии.
Спасибо....

Comment: "можно было визвать из `patern`"? Наверное parent? Передайте в качестве параметра и вызывайте когда захотите. В чем проблема?

Comment: а где можно посмотреть код этого API? Видимо я чего-то не понял, вы что хотите отправлять реальные `callback-functions` посредством `postMessage`?

Comment: ну это не возможно. Вопрос, скорее, как  эмитировать callback. может создать  общий слушатель в фрейме, и потом вызывать определенную функцию

Answer (score 0):

Нет, мы не можем передавать коллбэк через сообщения между окнами, так как данные обязательно должны быть либо простыми, либо наследовать от интерфейса [Transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable). Подразумевается, что новая вкладка работает в обособленном потоке и передаваемые данные обязательно должны быть статичными (неизменяемыми) - вы получаете их копию,  а не оригинал.

> This is an abstract interface and there is no object of this type. The
>   ArrayBuffer, MessagePort, ImageBitmap and OffscreenCanvas types
>   implement this interface.

Вы можете применить [The State Reducer Pattern](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions), передавая между окнами объект с данными (Action), который вызовет изменение состояния через специальную функцию с ветвлением (Reducer).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Frame</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Send message</button>
    <script>
      (function() {

        const ACTION = {
          SHOW_ALL: 'SHOW_ALL',
          SHOW_COMPLETED: 'SHOW_COMPLETED',
          SHOW_ACTIVE: 'SHOW_ACTIVE'
        }

        const handler = ({origin, data}) => {
          if (origin !== url) {
            return;
          }
          switch (data) {
            case ACTION.SHOW_ALL:
              alert('Show all');
              break;
            case ACTION.SHOW_COMPLETED:
              alert('Completed');
              break;
            case ACTION.SHOW_ACTIVE:
              alert('Show active');
              break;
            default:
              throw new Error(`Invalid action ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
          }
        }

        const { protocol, host, hash, href } = location;
        const url = `${protocol}//${host}`;
        const target = hash === "#child" ? opener : open(location.href + "#child");
        window.addEventListener('message', (e) => handler(e));
        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => 
          target.postMessage(ACTION.SHOW_ALL)
        );
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Для запуска используйте какой-нибудь веб сервер, например, встроенный поумолчанию в третий python:

```
python3 -m http.server
```